# Bash script behaves differently between local and remote execution

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, docker

I got the following script to run pre-backup stuff on my server :

```
#!/bin/bash
dump_name="nextcloud_$(date +%d-%m-%y_%H-%M-%S)_backup.sql"
printf "Enabling maintenance mode... " 
docker exec -u www-data nextcloud_front_1 sh -c "php occ maintenance:mode --on"
printf "\nDumping database...\n"
docker exec nextcloud_database_1 sh -c 'mysqldump -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD nextcloud' | sudo tee "/data/nextcloud/database/dumps/$dump_name" > /dev/null
```

This works normally when I run it on the server manually via SSH but I'd like to run it remotely :

```
ssh user@host 'bash -s' < script.sh
```

But then I get the following output among printf's:

```
" option does not exist.

maintenance:mode [--on] [--off]
```

Caused by this line

```
docker exec -u www-data nextcloud_front_1 sh -c "php occ maintenance:mode --on"
```

I tried the following :

```
docker exec -u www-data nextcloud_front_1 sh -c "php occ maintenance:mode --on"
docker exec -u www-data nextcloud_front_1 sh -c 'php occ maintenance:mode --on'
docker exec -u www-data nextcloud_front_1 php occ maintenance:mode --on
```

Also, running :

```
docker exec -u www-data nextcloud_front_1 echo 'php occ maintenance:mode --on'
```

Outputs as expected

```
php occ maintenance:mode --on
```

So I don't really have any idea where the error comes from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted a "?" at the end of my dumps name, turned out it was a ^M char induced by Notepad++ on windows (jokes on me for working on windows)

Ran

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

And everything runs fine now.